# ¿Cómo actualizar una coleccion con una arreglo json?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola me inicio en este mundo y tengo un arreglo json (lista) con el cuan necesito actualizar una coleccion llanada `User` a traves de metodo `findOneAndUpdate` de mongo, pero el codigo siemrre genera error y honestamente no se en que falla:

```
async function actualizarProceso(lista) {

  const arregloDePromesas = []

  lista.foreach((elemento) => {


    var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate({
      "_id": elemento._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        "pasarela": elemento.previo.pasarela,
        "fecha_fin": elemento.previo.fecha_fin,
        "dispositivos": elemento.previo.dispositivos,
        "estado_token": elemento.previo.estado_token
      }
    }).exec()

    arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)
  })

  //Cuando ya tienes todas las promesas listas las ejecutas asi:

  return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas)
    .then(datos => {
      resolve(datos)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

el error es: ReferenceError: resole is not defined, lo que si es siempre entra a reject por o que siemrpe da error, imagino porque la funcion est mal hecha.

disculpen mis errores, gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes poner el log del error?

Comment: gracias @hawks por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, con una función `async/await` no tienes `resolve` ni `reject` porque cualquier datos que devuelvas con `return` automaticamente se resolverá como una promesa. Y para errores puedes usar `return Promise.reject(err)`;

Segundo, como haces el return de `Promise.all(arregloDePromesas)` no hace falta que añadas el `then` y `catch` ahí. Lo puedes añadir en la función que llama `actualizarProceso`.

Osea así.

```
async function actualizarProceso(lista) {

  const arregloDePromesas = []

  lista.foreach((elemento) => {

    var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate({
      "_id": elemento._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        "pasarela": elemento.previo.pasarela,
        "fecha_fin": elemento.previo.fecha_fin,
        "dispositivos": elemento.previo.dispositivos,
        "estado_token": elemento.previo.estado_token
      }
    }).exec()

    arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)
  })

  //Cuando ya tienes todas las promesas listas las ejecutas asi:
  return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas);
}

function miFuncion() {
  const lista = [] // lo que sea
  actualizarProceso(lista)
    .then(datos => {
      // aqui tratas la response como quieras
      console.log(datos)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: Gracias @haks, disculpa mi ignoracia en el tema, estoy iniciando....gracias por tu tiempo...

Answer (score 0):

el error era de estructura aqui, el codigo que me funciona por si alguien lo necesita:

```
function actualizarProceso(lista) {

        const arregloDePromesas = []

        lista.map((elemento) =>{


              var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate( { "_id" : elemento._id },
              { $set: {  "pasarela" : elemento.previo.pasarela, "fecha_fin" : elemento.previo.fecha_fin, "dispositivos" : elemento.previo.dispositivos, "estado_token" : elemento.previo.estado_token    }}
              ).exec()

              arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)
       })

       //Cuando ya tienes todas las promesas listas las ejecutas asi:

       return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas).then(datos=>{ return(datos)})
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```